# How to concatenate datasets in Talend?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, talend, tmap

I would like to take two different datasets as an input and get the as an output the concatenation of the two datasets. There is a function in python pandas that do this job, called concat (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

Is there a simple way to that in Talend?

example:

dataset 1:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| AA | BB |

dataset 2:

| Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- |
| AB | C |
| BA | CC |

After concatenation you get:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | NaN |
| AA | BB | NaN |
| NaN | AB | C |
| NaN | BA | CC |

Tried with the tmap component but it seems like is not possible to concat the datasets with that component.

Comment: FYI, if my answer helps you, please mark it as such, i.e. mark it as the answer.  It rewards those who help and helps others who have the same question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Talend has a tUnite component for this purpose but it requires heterogeneous datasets you can use tMaps to make the datasets Heterogenous.

[image: Job Example]

please see the tMap config

[image: tMap configuration]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is exactly the outcome I was looking for!